# delete query affected rows return greater then 0 either there is no record in DB

Tags: php, mysql

this is a piece of code

```
    public static function delete_ques($ques_id) {
        $con = Connection::get_Connection();
        $sql_delete = "DELETE FROM question WHERE ques_id = " . $ques_id;
        $result_delete = $con->query($sql_delete);
        if ($result_delete->rowCount()) {
            $con->close();
            echo 'hell not ';
            return true;
        } else {
            $con->close();
            echo 'hell yes';
            return false;
        }
    }
```

i cannot figure it out why its happening

Comment: can you elaborate your query plz...

Comment: what you can do is first check if you have records with same ques_Id . if yes store it and then fire delete . if it return >0 then you are sure that some records where deleted .

Comment: either there is record or not it always return 1 row affected

Comment: @YashveerSingh the problem is not too big but due to that i cannot get my required message

Comment: but you can do something like if select returns records u can store a flag . and when delete return you can use && to see  IsRecordsPresent && DeleteSuccess then show the message else dont show

Comment: the returned 1 si not the number of rows affected  but the true value  for a correct sql statement

Comment: **WARNING**: When using PDO you should be using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) with placeholder values and supply any user data as separate arguments. In this code you have potentially severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Never use string interpolation or concatenation and instead use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and never put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly in your query. Refer to [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) for guidance with this and other problems.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing is because of **rowCount()**. according to php.net

> rowCount() returns the number of rows affected by the last DELETE, INSERT, or UPDATE statement executed by the corresponding **PDOStatement object**.

In your situation i would use affected_rows. So you if-else code block would be like this

```
if ($con->affected_rows) {
        $con->close();
        echo 'hell not ';
        return true;
} else {
        $con->close();
        echo 'hell yes';
        return false;
}
```